# Magento PayPal Standard orders don't update

Tags: paypal, order-status, paypal-standard

I have my shop online for testing now and I can't figure out why magento doesn't update the order status when a paypal payment has been made.
I'm using Paypal Website Payments Standard in Sandbox mode, the ssl option disabled. I see in the sellers Sandbox Paypal account that every IPN message gets a 200 response, the data also seems fine and there's no sign of an error in the logs.

```
 [business] => ****
        [invoice] => 100000009
        [currency_code] => EUR
        [paymentaction] => sale
        [return] => http://*********.de/paypal/standard/success/
        [cancel_return] => http://*********.de/paypal/standard/cancel/
        [notify_url] => http://*********.de/paypal/ipn/
        [bn] => MagentoCommerce_Cart_DEEdition
        [item_name] => SteinShop
        [lc] => de_DE
        [charset] => utf-8
        [amount] => 7.00
        [tax] => 0.00
        [shipping] => 4.90
        [discount_amount] => 0.00
        [item_number_1] => 
        [item_name_1] => Basic T-Shirt
        [quantity_1] => 1
        [amount_1] => 2.10
        [item_number_2] => Versandkosten - Standardversand
        [item_name_2] => Versand
        [quantity_2] => 1
        [amount_2] => 4.90
        [cmd] => _cart
        [upload] => 1
        [tax_cart] => 0.00
        [discount_amount_cart] => 0.00
        [city] => ****
        [country] => DE
        [email] => ****
        [first_name] => ****
        [last_name] => ****
        [zip] => ****
        [state] => 
        [address1] => ****
        [address2] => 
        [address_override] => 1
```

The order status just stays in pending payment and there's also no PayPal transaction ID visible in the backend.
Any Ideas what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to use Paypal Express checkout and this seems to work, but I still can't see why magento isn't processing payments with the normal "Website Payments Standard".